# Retrive firstnames from a list of names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with pubmed articles, and a column with the authors of each article, like this:

```
    DOI                             Fullnames
0   10.1016/0022-1759(96)00092-0    B I Korelitz, S C Sommers
1   10.1038/jhg.2017.16             Avi Saskin 1 , Vanessa Fulginiti 1 , Ashley ...
2   10.1007/s00415-005-0964-z       M Tiberio 1 , D T Chard, D R Altmann, G Davie...
3   10.1111/ene.13789               L Bonzano 1 , M Bove 2 , M P Sormani 3 , M ...
4   10.1038/s41598-018-19303-3      Dilek Yonar 1 , Levent Ocek 2 , Bedile Irem ...
5   10.1016/j.yebeh.2016.06.023     Klajdi Puka 1 , Luc Rubinger 2 , Carol Chan ...
6   10.3389/fnins.2019.00618        Paola Valsasina 1 , Milagros Hidalgo de la Cr...
7   10.5152/iao.2018.4467           Teruo Toi 1 , Yasuyuki Nomura 1 , Akihiro Ki...
8   10.1038/cdd.2016.71             Q Yang 1 , C Zheng 1 , J Cao 1 , G Cao 1 ,...
9   10.1002/j.2048-7940.2003        Alexa K Stuifbergen 1 , Tracie Culp Harrison
```

My aim is to obtain a column with a list of names of the authors, to then apply gender guesser to obtain a list of gender of authors. In order to do so I did the following:

1. Obtain a column with a clean list of authors for each article

```
# First create a column with clean list of authors
df['Authorlist']=''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  try:
    Fullnames=df.loc[index, 'Fullnames']
    authors=list(Fullnames.split(","))
    Allauthors = []
    for author in authors:
      author=''.join([i for i in author if not i.isdigit()])
      author=author.rstrip()
      author=author.lstrip()
      Allauthors.append(author)
    df.loc[index, 'Authorlist']=Allauthors
  except:
    pass
```

2. To try to impute names for authors with just the first letter of the firstname, I create a list of author for which the firstname is available, so that later when I encounter an incomplete name I try to look in the list and see if the authors appeared elsewhere with a complete firstname

```
# Create a list of authors with available first names
Authorswithfullnameslist=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  try:
    #Fullnames=df.loc[index, 'Authorlist']
    for author in df.loc[index, 'Authorlist']:
      firstname=author.split()[0]
      if len(firstname) > 1:
        Authorswithfullnameslist.append(author)
  except:
    pass
```

Up to this point everything is working fine. Then, when I try to create a column with a list of firstnames, things don't go well, as you can see the final result is not correct and I don't understand where I am wrong

```
# Create a column with clean list of names
df['Nameslist']=''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  try:
    Names=[]
    for author in df.loc[index, 'Authorlist']:
      firstname=author.split()[0]
      surname=author.split()[-1]
      if len(firstname) > 1:
        Names.append(firstname)
      elif len(firstname) < 2:
        for completeauthor in Authorswithfullnameslist:
          if surname == completeauthor.split()[-1]:
            firstnamecorrect = completeauthor.split()[0]
            if firstnamecorrect[0] == firstname[0]:
              Names.append(firstnamecorrect) 
    df.loc[index, 'Nameslist']=Names
  except:
    pass
```

```
    Fullnames                                       Authorlist                  Nameslist
0   B I Korelitz, S C Sommers                       [B I Korelitz, S C Sommers]        []
1   Avi Saskin 1 , Vanessa Fulginiti 1 , Ashley ... [Avi Saskin, Vanessa Fulginiti, Ashley H Birch...   [Avi, Vanessa, Ashley, Yannis]
2   M Tiberio 1 , D T Chard, D R Altmann, G Davie...[M Tiberio, D T Chard, D R Altmann, G Davies, ...   [Daniel, Mary, Alan, Alan, Aiko, Alan, David, ...
3   L Bonzano 1 , M Bove 2 , M P Sormani 3 , M ...  [L Bonzano, M Bove, M P Sormani, M L Stromillo...   [Maria, Maria, Maria, Maria, Antonio, Antonio,...
4   Dilek Yonar 1 , Levent Ocek 2 , Bedile Irem ... [Dilek Yonar, Levent Ocek, Bedile Irem Tiftikc...   [Dilek, Levent, Bedile, Yasar, Feride]
5   Klajdi Puka 1 , Luc Rubinger 2 , Carol Chan ... [Klajdi Puka, Luc Rubinger, Carol Chan, Mary L...   [Klajdi, Luc, Carol, Mary, Elysa]
6   Paola Valsasina 1 , Milagros Hidalgo de la Cr...[Paola Valsasina, Milagros Hidalgo de la Cruz,...   [Paola, Milagros, Massimo, Maria]
7   Teruo Toi 1 , Yasuyuki Nomura 1 , Akihiro Ki... [Teruo Toi, Yasuyuki Nomura, Akihiro Kishino, ...   [Teruo, Yasuyuki, Akihiro, Shuntaro, Takeshi, ...
8   Q Yang 1 , C Zheng 1 , J Cao 1 , G Cao 1 ,...   [Q Yang, C Zheng, J Cao, G Cao, P Shou, L Lin,...   [Ying, Yi, Ying, Yu]
9   Alexa K Stuifbergen 1 , Tracie Culp Harrison    [Alexa K Stuifbergen, Tracie Culp Harrison]       [Alexa, Tracie]
```

Could you help me understand where i am wrong, or anyother way of achieving the result?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the final result is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you say the results are incorrect because of the 8th row of your dataframe. You can see there that all the first names start with Y, so this shows you the potential failure mode of your method.

In the 8th row most of the authors are Chinese (looking at the surnames) and Chinese surnames are not very varied. So you matched the surname several times, and because the author's real first name started with Y, you saved all the `completeauthor` first names that start with Y.

##### Potential remedy

Once you add a name from the `Authorswithfullnamelist` exit the entire loop to prevent more matches. Clearly, this will only add the first found surname match which may not be correct. However, your method is not guaranteed to be correct from the start, so hopefully this at least prevents you from adding more first names for each author.